# Decimal rounding issues

Tags: c#, testing, selenium-webdriver, automation

I have a scenario in which some variable values have decimal values, the values can have leading .0, .234, .124, .125, numbers like this, and so on. If the number has leading decimal and zero it should ignore and if a number has leading 3 or more numbers it should round off to two.
Let's say the code is as follows:

```
var anone    = "23"
var antwo    = "23.0"
var anthree  = "23.467"
var anfour   = "23.125"
```

In order to remove the leading decimal and zero I have used the following method:

```
 var removingzero = antwo.Replace(".0", "");
 // The result will be = 23
```

In order to round off and limit the number to two decimal points I have used the following method:

```
 var convertodecimal = Decimal.Parse(anthree);
 var roundtotwo      = Math.Round(convertodecimal, 2);
 // The result will be = 23.47
```

similarly in order to convert the last one I follow the same method:

```
 var convertodecimal = Decimal.Parse(anfour);
 var roundtotwo      = Math.Round(convertodecimal, 2);
 // The result will be = 23.12
 // But the Result should be = 23.13
```

So, the problem is when I am trying to round off any number like the last example it does not do it, how can I fix it.

Comment: And why should 23.125 rounded to two decimal points round to 23.13.  You are using a specific rounding rule in your head. The framework is using a different one (round to even).  Did you look at the docs for Math.Round https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?  They discuss this.  As does this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.midpointrounding?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: If you are curious why round-to-even is good, take the sequence 1, 1.5, 2, ... 10.5 and take its average (5.75).  Now round each value using round-away-from-zero (what your teacher taught you) and take the average (6).  But, if you use round-to-even, the average is 5.75.  You can do this in Excel (but the ROUND function there always uses Round-away-from-zero, I believe)

Comment: What if you have a number like `"23.04"`? After the `Replace(".0", "")` line, it will be `"234"`.

Comment: I haven't come across this issue yet, but thanks for bringing it up something to keep in the mind :)

Comment: you wouldn't believe, I have been using the above-mentioned method for months and no issues and couple days ago you mention this and today I have been seeing the values in the way you mentioned lol so how would I get rid of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your question is a long way of asking *"How can I force rounding UP when a decimal number ends in `5`?"*

If that's the case, then you can use [the overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=netcore-3.1#System_Math_Round_System_Decimal_System_Int32_System_MidpointRounding_) of `Math.Round` that takes a [`MidpointRounding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.midpointrounding?view=netcore-3.1) argument, and specify either `MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero` or `MidpointRounding.ToPositiveInfinity`.

The behavior of these is the same for positive numbers, but difference is seen with negative numbers, where `-23.125` will round to `-23.13` if `AwayFromZero` is specified, or `-23.12` if `ToPositiveInfinity` is specified.

So your code might look like this instead:

```
var roundtotwo = Math.Round(convertodecimal, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for the explanation and it did solve the issues and I implemented this throughout the system :)

Answer (score 1):

Try by changing your Math.Round() to below one:

`Math.Round(num,2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)`